# Javascript, "foreach" binding in knockout, "html" binding buttons dont work

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a problem with such code:

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>

     <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody data-bind="foreach: cars">
                <tr>
                  <td data-bind="html: button"> </td>
                </tr>    
              </tbody>
            </table>


    <script> var tab = [
    {lat: 50.29655, lng: 18.65656},
    { lat: 51.29655, lng: 18.6565},
    { lat: 51.29655, lng: 19.6565},
    { lat: 50.29655, lng: 19.6565}
    ];

    var size = tab.length;

    function AppViewModel() {
        button: ko.observable();

        this.cars = ko.observableArray([
        ]);

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                var buttonString = '<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-bind="click: position' + i + '">Show &raquo;</a></p>';
                this.cars.push({button:buttonString });
            }


    this.position0 = function() {
        alert(1);     
        }; 
    this.position1 = function() {
        alert(2);
        };      
    this.position2 = function() {
        alert(3);
        };
    this.position3 = function() {
        alert(4);
        };  
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());</script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

There are four buttons generated by "foreach" bind basing on the size of "tab". Then I bind them using "html bind" to work like buttons. But they dont work. Each of them should invoke fucntion "position0", "position1" etc. but I dont see any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout doesn't apply bindings to HTML created with the `html` binding. Either use a template for the button content or just write the HTML out and don't try to dynamically generate method names:

```
<td><p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-bind="click: position.bind(null, $index + i)">Show &raquo;</a></p></td>
```

and then

```
this.position=function(index) {
  // do what's appropriate based on index
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to do this is so

```
var buttonString = '<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" onclick="position' + i + '">Show &raquo;</a></p>';
 this.cars.push({button:buttonString });
```

because I see the knockout in the middle of this bind and will not hold for the new content